# "those which he thinks likeliest to..."

Tags: sentence-structure

The following is an excerpt from the book ["Algorithms to Live By"](https://books.google.co.kr/books/about/Algorithms_to_Live_By.html?id=Ydn_CwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) by Brian Christian. (p. 230)

> ...; so that each competitor has to pick, not those faces which he himself finds prettiest, but **those which he thinks likeliest to** catch the fancy of the other competitors, all of whom are looking at the problem from the same point of view.

I understand what the phrase means, but I'm not so clear about the grammatical structure.

Is "be" verb being omitted as in "those which [he thinks] (are) likeliest to..."? I assume "he thinks" is a mere inserted phrase, so "be likely to" should be the main verb.

My second-guessing goes "think likely." Can you use "think likely" in a similar way to "is/seem/appear likely"?

Comment: _...Those which he thinks **are** the most likely to..._

Comment: You are correct in saying that _to be_ has been omitted. "He has to pick... those which, he thinks, are [the] likeliest to..." As you say, _he thinks_ is a parenthesis, rather than _thinks likely_ being a phrasal verb.

Answer (score -1):

Your second guess is correct: You can think something likely/pretty/..., just like you can find it likely etc.